# no PHP errors on Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Why is it that I never get any PHP errors? Where can you deactivate/activate it?

have tried to put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the top of my code, but still no display errors

I'm on my own dedicated server so have permission to change the settings needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to errors displayed on the webpage, you can enable it in php.ini (it is typically disabled for security on production systems). The value is called 'display_errors' (set to 1 to enable).

Alternatively, you can enable it on a per-script basis using the PHP error_reporting function.

In your PHP script add: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

OR use: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

(Keep in mind that some hosts might not permit modifying certain values with ini_set. You should try the error_reporting function in preference.

If you are referring to errors in your server logs, ensure that error logging is enabled in your httpd.conf (for apache).

Comment: I'm on my own dedicated server so I have permission to change all settings.. but I can't make `error_reporting(E_ALL);` work.. I just put it in the top of my code

Comment: (I presume of course, there is an actual error to display); Set the error_reporting and display_errors values in php.ini (See: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Comment: there is an error.. but when using `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` not all errors are shown compared to when changing `display_errors` in php.ini

Comment: If some errors are displayed, and you want to see more errors, change the value of error_reporting. Either use error_reporting(-1) to see all errors or try error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); See: http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 1):

in php.ini search for

- display_errors and set it to ON,
- check error_reporting for configuration (default is E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE)
- check if log_errors is on, if yes, then they are logging somewhere specified by error_log
- check your source for functions which can change those values and check for funcions set_error_handler which can set custom error handler

Answer (score 1):

error reporting is set in your php.ini file

check the settings for error_reporting and display errors display_errors.

In dev env they should be:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL|E_STRICT
display_errors = On
```